# How to see a function as a vector in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

I know that strictly speaking my question is some sort of a duplicate of at least [this previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83493/how-to-think-of-a-function-as-a-vector) and I am quite sorry for that (usually I try to get the best from previous questions), but still I did not find an answer that suited my intuition, probably because not enough developed. Still, I would really like to grasp in the proper way this important point.

As a side problem, I think that a question that general can be problematic to answer, so I see it is not easy. Anyway, coming up with a specific example (or minimal working problem) could be a decent starting point. Thus, here we are.

Let's take as a building block a continuous function over $[0,1]$. When we are asked to think about this object as a vector in a vector space, is this object a vector with infinitely many elements?

Does it make sense what I wrote?

Thanks a lot to any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two thought-patterns which I would like to encourage:

1. Relax your mind and stop thinking of vectors as lists of numbers! Vectors are just elements of a vector space, and that just means you can add and subtract elements since they form an additive abelian group, and you can also multiply these things with scalars. (Of course I am omitting a few connecting axioms in the interest of brevity.) Functions can be elements of sets that are vector spaces, so there is no reason to think of them any differently.
2. After digesting the last point, I'll tell you that you **can** still visualize function as vectors. It's just that this vector has a *lot* of entries, so many that you can't even write the entries sequentially. For each number $r\in [0,1]$, you can just think of the "$r$th coordinate" of the vector, and there is a real number there. The number at the $r$th coordinate is $f(r)$. In this way, this very long vector (with as many entries as $[0,1]$ has elements) captures the entire function. Finally, notice that vector addition and scaling  of these "function-vectors" matches the operation of pointwise addition and scaling of functions.

Comment: @ rschwieb: Just a couple of points: 1) I absolutely love your "Relax your mind and stop thinking of vectors as lists of numbers"… it should be inserted in any linear algebra book when it comes to this topic.

Comment: 2) thus, indeed, a function in $C[0,1]$ is a vector in that vector space with uncountably infinite entries, right? That absolutely helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @Kolmin Definitely. Linear algebra classes nowadays are especially guilty of obscuring the big picture with details. Texts in this subject are still struggling to find the right balance for the right audiences.

Comment: @Kolmin In essence, all vector spaces *are* just lists of entries, but it seems like that hampers some thinking for beginning and intermediate students. An advanced student who grasps the abstract picture can then go back and appreciate in what sense vector spaces are lists of entries.

Comment: @Kolmin Oh, I forgot to address your comment-question. Yes, it's true that $C[0,1]$ is an uncountably infinite dimensional $\Bbb R$ vector space. The picture I described above can be translated into an injective map of $C[0,1]\to\Bbb R^{|[0,1]|}$, so it is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{|[0,1]|}$

Comment: I can tell you as a self-thaught student what made me wrongly doubts about that intution that a function in $C[0,1]$ vector space is a vector with uncountably infinite entries… the gap between finite and infinite. In linear algebra everything is emphasized towards the finite side of the world, and then - all of a sudden - you find that a function is a vector and you have your intuition broken between how infinity should enter in the big picture and how you should kind of maintain the discourse finite.

Comment: @Kolmin That's another good point.

Comment: actually my last question in which I put $C[01]$ is just the same previous question. I can see why $C[0,1]$ is a vector space with uncountably infinite vectors. My question was a quick summary about one specific vector, and not the vector space. Actually you have already answered me at that question with the enlightening "In this way, this very long vector (with as many entries as $[0,1]$ has elements) captures the entire function".

Answer (score 0):

Your example is formally denoted as $C[0,1]$ and wr.t. pointwise addition and multiplication it forms a vector space (simply because it satisfies all the criteria for it). Now any element of a vector space is a vector in that space so any $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous is a vector in $C[0,1]$. Now how many such $f$'s can you define ? obviously infinitely many of them. Hence $C[0,1]$ has infinite number of vectors.

Comment: Ok, this is something I partly know and I can see. My problem is not if $C[0,1]$ as a vector space has infinitely many vectors. My problem is how I have to visualize a single function as a vector in that vector space.

Comment: what do you mean by visualising a vector ? do you mean that whether it has a $magnitude$ and a $direction$. ? if yes, then note that given a vector space any element belonging to it is a vector...

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$, then $f\in C[0,1]$...and you visualise it as you visualise $f(x)=x$.

Comment: I mean more or less what I wrote in a comment over there, namely "a function in $C[0,1]$ is a vector in that vector space with uncountably infinite entries", which was what I fuzzily thought and was confirmed in an answer and what my problem was really all about.